# A proof on the generating subset of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a beginner and currently reading Fraleigh's textbook "A first course in abstract algebra". Is this sentence true of false? (I didn't find such a "theorem" in this textbook or in the practice problems)

> If subgroup $H$ is generated by subset $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_k\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$ for infinite case), where $1\le a_1<a_2<...<a_k \le n-1$,
> then $H= \langle d \rangle$, where $d=\gcd(a_1, a_2, ...,a_k)$

And I try to prove it in the following way (both finite and infinite case):

Because $H$ is Abelian, we can write $H=\{m_1 a_1+...+m_k a_k~|~m_1\in \mathbb{Z},...,m_k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$

(1) For any $x\in H$, $x=m_1 a_1+...+m_k a_k$ for some $m_1\in \mathbb{Z},...,m_k\in \mathbb{Z}$,

Since $d=\gcd(a_1, a_2, ...,a_k)$, which means $d|a_1,...,d|a_k$, so $a_1=r_1 d, ...,a_k=r_kd$, where $r_1\in \mathbb{Z},...,r_k\in \mathbb{Z}$

$x=m_1r_1d+...+m_kr_kd=(m_1r_1+...+m_kr_k)d$, so, $x\in \langle d \rangle$,

Therefore, $H\subseteq \langle d \rangle$

(2) For any $x\in \langle d \rangle$, $x=rd$, where $r\in \mathbb{Z}$,

Because $d=\gcd(a_1, a_2, ...,a_k)$, there exists $r_1\in \mathbb{Z},...,r_k\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $r_1a_1+...+r_ka_k=d$ ([Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity))

so we have: $x=r(r_1a_1+...+r_ka_k)=(rr_1)a_1+...+(rr_k)a_k$, so, $x\in H$

Therefore, $\langle d \rangle \subseteq H$

By (1) and (2), we have $H=\langle d \rangle$.

---

Question: If this proof is correct, according to the isomorphism, $\mathbb{Z}_n\longleftrightarrow \text{"finite cyclic group"}$, $\mathbb{Z}\longleftrightarrow \text{"infinite cyclic group"}$, it is also true for all cyclic groups, right?

Comment: I think you did pretty well.   You used Bezout too, of course.   Since $H$ and $\langle d\rangle $ are subgroups,  you can just prove they're equal as sets, if you like.

Comment: Thank you, and what about the Question.2 and Question.3 ?

Comment: Well,  there's only one infinite cyclic group.   And it's subgroups are all of the form $\langle d\rangle $.

Comment: What I mean is for example, if $H$ is generated by $\{ 12, 20, 28\}$ of $Z$, then $H=<4>=4Z=\{...-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,...\}$, and I can prove this infinite case by using the exactly the same way as above proof, right?

Comment: Yeah,  I think it works.

Comment: Got it, thank you :)

Comment: Notice you can use `$\langle d \rangle$` to produce $\langle d \rangle$, which looks much nicer than $<d>$.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I don't know that symbol, yes, it is much better and I learn it! @HallaSurvivor